# How to document javadoc exception cause for multiple methods

Tags: java, documentation, javadoc

is there a way to specify the way an exception cause gets documented?

i have a class with a bunch of methods, which all throw nearly the same exceptions; example:

```
/**
 * some doc
 * @return value
 * @throws SpecificException when X happens
 */
public int fn1() throws SpecificException{
    return 0;
}

/**
 * some different doc
 * @return value
 * @throws SpecificException when X happens
 */
public int fn2() throws SpecificException{
    return 0;
}
```

i want to avoid copypasting the documentation for the @throws things.

is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do it using the standard javadoc tool and standard tags.

It is possible in theory to define custom javadoc tags and a custom `Doclet` class that propagates the common documentation comments across multiple methods.  However, that makes your javadocs dependent on your customized `javadoc` setup.  Furthermore, someone studying your APIs by looking at the source code is likely to miss that the comments for one method apply to others.

In short, its a bad idea.  You are better off cut-and-pasting the relevant parts of the javadoc comments ... IMO.

Comment: i agree with you..that applying any overcustomized magic would be bad ;)